# Jar with two main classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jar

There is a jar file being generated with Gradle, it is a spring--boot application, and the ask is to add a second main class, so that jar can be also executed via command line.

So far what I have done is add a new java class:

```
package com.the.springboot.mainclass;
public class SomeServiceCli {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("some text!!")
    }
}
```

when I build with gradle I see this new class in the jar, and the manifest is like this:

```
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: com.the.springboot.mainclass.SomeClass
```

So, when I try to execute the generated jar with this command:

```
java -cp someJar.jar com.the.springboot.mainclass.SomeServiceCli
```

I get ClassNotFoundException : com.the.springboot.mainclass.SomeServiceCli, and I wonder why ? since the class is in the classpath, Ive checked using

```
jar -xf someJar.jar
```

any ideas?

Comment: Spring boot has its own (slightly weird) executable jar format [described here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html#appendix.executable-jar.nested-jars.jar-structure). Instead of a normal jar with everything in it, it's only got a simple loader directly in it and everything else as in a different directory structure that requires a dedicated class loader.

Comment: Hi @JoachimSauer, Ive tryed puting the to mains in the same package, and I have the exact same issue, I will edit the question

Comment: Not totally sure about this but try `java -cp someJar.jar -Dloader.main=com.the.springboot.mainclass.SomeServiceCli`

Comment: Hi @g00se, thanks for tour comment, that particular command fails since -cp expects two parameters, if I add the two parrameters + the -Dloader flag I still get the same exception

Comment: No, `-cp` expects *one* parameter. There should be no spaces. e.g. `-cp jar1.jar:jar2.jar:./dir1:./dir2` or  `-cp jar1.jar;jar2.jar;./dir1;./dir2` (Windows)

Comment: are you suggesting `java -cp someJar.jar:com.the.springboot.mainclass.SomeServiceCli -Dloader.main=com.the.springboot.mainclass.SomeServiceCli` ?

Comment: Just to clarify: there *can* be spaces in an individual path but it's still *one* parameter, e.g. `-cp 'dir1:dir 2 with space'`

Comment: I am happy to try anything, let me know how the command would look like and I will give it a try, Im running windows

Comment: As to your question, I can't say what your classpath should be as I don't know. It probably couldn't be what you suggest since what follows that colon does *not* look like a path. Is `SomeServiceCli` in the jar? Oh and another reason: the path separator is a *semi*colon for Windows

Comment: `SomeServiceCli` is a java class, `SomeServiceCli` is in the jar, when I decompress it I see it next to `com.the.springboot.mainclass.SomeClass`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244883/discussion-between-g00se-and-facundo-laxalde).